# Auto_Increment increments column number on providing duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have created a table in mysql:

```
create table persons( ID int auto_increment, Name varchar(100), Mobile bigint unique , primary key (ID));
```

I inserted this row:

```
insert into persons(Name, Mobile) values ('Ritesh', 123);
```

Then I tried to insert this row:

```
insert into persons(Name, Mobile) values ('Naman', 123);
```

But I got an error: `ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '123' for key 'persons.Mobile'`

Then, I tried to insert again:

```
insert into persons(Name, Mobile) values ('Sushil', 125);
```

The ID column was incremented from 1 to 3.

```
select * from persons
+----+--------+--------+
| ID | Name   | Mobile |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | Ritesh |    123 |
|  3 | Sushil |    125 |
+----+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I solve this error.

Comment: It's not an error it's expected behaviour.And an auto_increment field should have no business meaning for this reason.

Comment: @P.Salmon So, how can I prevent ID from being incremented if someone provides duplicate entries ?

Comment: E.g `Insert ignore`, `on duplicate key` - there's a whole manual dedicated to this stuff, but just don't worry about the ids

Comment: Do you want more than 1 person to share a mobile if so don't make it unique.